# How can we apply same column configure settings to multiple frames in python tkinter?

Tags: tkinter, grid

Is there anyway we apply same `grid.coluumnconfigure` as we defined for the most first `frame`, for every `frame` we make in Python `tkinter` ?

I basically wanted to make a `ttk.Treeview` type thing but I couldn't make one because of this problem.

Like `ttk.Treeview` has header that adjusts the size of its columns.

Comment: Create a custom `Frame` class with required `columnconfigure(...)`, then use this class for the frames.

Comment: @acw1668: You should post this as an answer, if you want the OP to accept it.